# How to read blob that are being uploaded to separate folders in the container into Stream Analytics job

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-stream-analytics

I have few IOT Devices in the central application and they are sending telemetry to the Azure blob container.
For each blob there is a seperate folder being created into the container(based on the upload time). Following snapshot shows the directories, in a similar war multiple directories/subdirectories are being created to store the blob.
[image]

How can I read this data into my Stream analytics job.
I have a Stream analytics job with blob container as input, even though the container is continuously receiving data but it isn't showing any data when I run the select * query.
Please let me know how am I supposed to get blob input into stream analytics where each blob is stored in a separate folder in the container.

Comment: Could you please detail how your blob streaming input has been setup in terms of its [path pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#configure-blob-storage-as-a-stream-input). Note that this attribute is optional only of you read all files from the root. If not, you need to have at least one of {date}, {time}, or {partition} in your pattern

Comment: Currently I haven't configured anything for path bcoz the issue is that everyday files will be added so I want to read all of them, in that case how can I specify the data in path pattern ?

Comment: What is the meaning of these sub folders in the picture? Are these days? Are they located in months sub folders? Themselves in years? Let me know what pattern is used to publish those files in storage and I can help you configure the input in ASA.

Comment: I've updated the snapshot in question. So in a similar way for each day,month, time separate folder is bring created and the final folder has exactly 1 entry which is the blob file as available in snap. To publish these files into storage I have just created an export job in IOT Central App.
The final blob file name is same in all the folders.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if we have large amount of data, pulling them by query will take time.

Try to get the data as below:

```
SELECT
    BlobName,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    BlobLastModifiedUtcTime
FROM Input
```

You can also specify tokens such as {date}, {time} on the path prefix pattern to help guide Stream Analytics on the files to read.

when the job was running for long enough, there appeared to be some output. And in those output records we can notice that big delay between my custom timestamp field and the general timestamp field

For detail understanding about how to configure the streaming inputs refer to [blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/processing-data-with-azure-stream-analytics/)

Also, if you want to read blobs from the root of the container, do not set a path pattern. Within the path, you can specify one or more instances of the following three variables: {date}, {time}, or {partition}